# How to check if a View is VISIBLE on a specific RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I am new to using espresso. I cannot really get what I wanted to test using this code:

```
    onData(withId(R.id.relativelayout_tag))
        .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.recyclerview_tag_list))
        .onChildView(withId(R.id.imageview_tag))
        .atPosition(1)
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Where `R.id.imageview_tag` is a child of `R.id.relativelayout_tag`. `R.id.relativelayout_tag` holds the entire content for my adapter item. `R.id.recyclerview_tag_list` is the name of my `RecyclerView` on which I assigned a particular `RecyclerView` `Adapter`.

This is a very very basic test. Here are the user procedures:

1. Select, **SPECIFICALLY**, the first item on the `RecyclerView` (I don't really care what
   text is on the view). Also do not suggest using view text to identify the first item. **I DONT CARE ABOUT THE ADAPTER ITEM'S CONTENT** or even putting a unique tag on some view.
2. On select, the indicator view(An ImageView that shows that the item
   is selected) should appear.

Very basic and simple. It is so hard to write a test for this basic user story using Espresso. When I run that particular test it always fail stating this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView and is displayed on the screen to the user)
Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131624115, res-name=recyclerview_tag_list, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=1032, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=15}"
```

It doesn't make sense as I have the list already visible. I can even run this test just fine:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview_tag_list))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions
            .actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));
```

Here is the full test:

```
@Test
public void shouldTagToggleSelected()
{
    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview_tag_list))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions
            .actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));

    onData(withId(R.id.relativelayout_tag))
        .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.recyclerview_tag_list))
        .onChildView(withId(R.id.imageview_tag))
        .atPosition(1)
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    //onView(withId(R.id.imageview_tag))
    //        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

What I wanted to test if the indicator view has a visibility set to `visible` **ONLY on that particular item** (or any item of my choosing).

Any thoughts? Maybe I missed something dearly.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`onData` does not work with `RecyclerView` as `RecyclerView` does not extend `AdapterView`.

You need to use `onView` to make your assertions. If it's the first item in the recycler view, then you can use something like this matcher to make your assertion:

```
public static Matcher<View> withViewAtPosition(final int position, final Matcher<View> itemMatcher) {
        return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                itemMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
                final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
                return viewHolder != null && itemMatcher.matches(viewHolder.itemView);
            }
        };
}
```

And the usage is the following:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview_tag_list))
            .check(matches(withViewAtPosition(1, hasDescendant(allOf(withId(R.id.imageview_tag), isDisplayed())))));
```

Keep in mind that this matcher will fail if your ViewHolder has not been laid out yet. If that's the case you need to scroll to the ViewHolder with [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html). You don't need to scroll if you are clicking the item in the test prior to using the matcher.

Comment: Hi I edited your answer. It should be `onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview_tag_list))`, I know this is what you mean. Thanks I am able to pass the test now. I am still little bit struggling to get a sense of BoundedMatchers. I try to avoid them if I could. It seems not this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had an exception error when checking element linear layout that was not visible. To resolve it, I had to add withFailureHandler as follows:

```
class MyTest {

        boolean isViewVisible = true;

        public void test1(){

           onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recycler_view)
                .atPositionOnView(index, R.id.linear_layout))
                .withFailureHandler(new FailureHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Throwable error, Matcher<View> viewMatcher){

                        isViewVisible = false;                            
                    }
                })
          .check(isVisible());

          //wait for failure handler to finish
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          if(isViewVisible){

              //do something
          }
        }
}

class MyTestUtil {

    public static RecyclerViewMatcher withRecyclerView(final int recyclerViewId) {

        return new RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId);
    }

    public static ViewAssertion isVisible() {

        return new ViewAssertion() {
            public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noView) {
                assertThat(view, new VisibilityMatcher(View.VISIBLE));
            }
        };
    }
}


public class RecyclerViewMatcher {
    private final int recyclerViewId;

    public RecyclerViewMatcher(int recyclerViewId) {
        this.recyclerViewId = recyclerViewId;
    }

    public Matcher<View> atPosition(final int position) {
        return atPositionOnView(position, -1);
    }

    public Matcher<View> atPositionOnView(final int position, final int targetViewId) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            Resources resources = null;
            View childView;

            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                String idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId);
                if (this.resources != null) {
                    try {
                        idDescription = this.resources.getResourceName(recyclerViewId);
                    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException var4) {
                        idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)",
                                new Object[] { Integer.valueOf
                                        (recyclerViewId) });
                    }
                }

                description.appendText("with id: " + idDescription);
            }

            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

                this.resources = view.getResources();

                if (childView == null) {
                    RecyclerView recyclerView =
                            (RecyclerView) view.getRootView().findViewById(recyclerViewId);
                    if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.getId() == recyclerViewId) {
                        childView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if (targetViewId == -1) {
                    return view == childView;
                } else {
                    View targetView = childView.findViewById(targetViewId);
                    return view == targetView;
                }

            }
        };
    }
}
```